# How to calculate the curve of a linear floating point number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, logarithm, curve

How do I calculate a curve of a linear floating point number (0 to 1) and get another floating point number as a result? What I want is up until the half (0..0.5), to be inversed logarithmic and high than that to be logarithmic like a curve according to the given **linear** value.

Comment: I find the question hard to understand...

Comment: I', sorry, but I don't really understand what it is you are trying to do.

are you saying, you will get a value X

if X is less then 0.5 display inverse log of X

if X is greater the 0.5 display log of X

Do you actually have a set of numbers in sequence or something? How are you can't calculate a curve or line or much else with just one number.

And as for drawing it, JS is not that cleaver for drawing, though you could try some mad DOM manipulation, moving around 1px square divs as dots on a graph background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you are looking for is a function to do:

```
double x, y;
y = 1.0 / log(x) {x = 0 .. 0.5}
    log(x)     {x = 0.5 .. 1}
```

??

or:

```
y = exp(x) {x = 0 .. 0.5}
```

??